# Using IF statements in a form to narrow choices down

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I basically want to limit my choices in my form so that when a car is chosen as well as the transmission only certain colors may appear. I have created the form. The problem is creating the code in the Javascript file. I don't know how to make it so that if Car 1 is chosen as well as Automatic then for example only Black and blue appear as options. Im relatively new to coding and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**HTML**

```
<script src="Script\configurator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form name="CarConfigurator">
   <select name="Car_make" onchange="Transmission(this.value);">
      <option value=" " selected="selected">None</option>
      <option value="1">Audi RS6</option>
      <option value="2">BMW M4</option>
      <option value="3">Mercedes C63 AMG</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   <br>
   <select name="A_M" >
      <option value="" selected="selected">None</option>
      <option value="1" selected="selected">Automatic</option>
      <option value="2" selected="selected">Manual</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   <br>
   <select name="Color">
      <option value="" selected="selected">None</option>
      <option value="1">Black</option>
      <option value="2">Blue</option>
      <option value="3">Red</option>
      <option value="4">White</option>
      <option value="5">Green</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function Transmission(Car) {
    var make = document.CarConfigurator.A_M;
    make.options.length = 0;
    if (Car == "1") {
        make.options[make.options.length] = new Option('Automatic','1');
        make.options[make.options.length] = new Option ('Manual','2');
    }
    if (Car =="2" ) {
        make.options[make.options.length] = new Option('Manual','2');
    }
    if (Car == "3") {
        make.options[make.options.length] = new Option('Automatic','3');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="CarConfigurator">
        <select name="Car_make" onchange="Transmission();">
            <option value=" " selected="selected">None</option>
            <option value="1">Audi RS6</option>
            <option value="2">BMW M4</option>
            <option value="3">Mercedes C63 AMG</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <select name="A_M" onchange="Transmission();">
            <option value="" selected="selected">None</option>
            <option value="1" selected="selected">Automatic</option>
            <option value="2" selected="selected">Manual</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <select name="Color" onchange="ChoicesMade();">
            <option value="" selected="selected">None</option>
            <option value="1">Black</option>
            <option value="2">Blue</option>
            <option value="3">Red</option>
            <option value="4">White</option>
            <option value="5">Green</option>
        </select>
        <div id="imageContainer" style="display: none;"><img src="http://buyersguide.caranddriver.com/media/assets/submodel/6873.jpg" /></div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Transmission() {
            var Car = document.CarConfigurator.Car_make.value;
            var make = document.CarConfigurator.A_M.value;
            var color = document.CarConfigurator.Color;
            color.options.length = 0;
            if (Car == "1" && make == '1') {
                color.options.add(new Option('Black', '1'));
                color.options.add(new Option('Blue', '2'));
            }
            else if(Car == '2' && make == '1')
            {
                color.options.add(new Option('Red', '3'));
                color.options.add(new Option('White', '4'));
            }
            ChoicesMade();
        }

        function ChoicesMade()
        {
            var form = document.CarConfigurator;
            var car = form.Car_make.value;
            var make = form.A_M.value;
            var color = form.Color.value;
            if(car != ' ' && make != '' && color != '')
            {
                var imageContainer = document.querySelector('#imageContainer');
                imageContainer.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah that it. Thanks.

Comment: Too add more colors to different cars what would I do? Else If statements? Or something else. Like if I wanted to give a different car  different color choices. And would it be difficult to make an image appear once all choices have been made?

Comment: `Else if` or `switch` statement is ok, either way, @Duncher. And it would not be very difficult to show/hide an image.

Comment: ok cool . Could you give an example of some code to show an image. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use objects in JavaScript and then loop through each array in object to change options. For example

```
var cars = {
"Audi_RS6":{
    "name":"Audi RS6",
    "Automatic":["color_1","color_2"],
    "Manual":["color_1","color_2"]
    },
"BMW_M4":{
    "name":"BMW M4",
    "Manual":["color_1","color_2"]
    },
"Mercedes_C63_AMG":{
    "name":"Mercedes C63 AMG",
    "Automatic":["color_1","color_2"]
    }
};
```

values can be accessed like this

```
var result = cars.Audi_RS6.Manual[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go Duncher, this code does exactly what you want

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html><head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="CarConfigurator">
        <select id="car" name="Car_make">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Which car?</option>
            <option value="car1">Audi RS6</option>
            <option value="car2">BMW M4</option>
            <option value="car3">Mercedes C63 AMG</option>
            </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <select id="trans" name="A_M">
            <option value="" selected="selected">What trans?</option>
            <option value="auto">Automatic</option>
            <option value="man">Manual</option>
            </select>
        <br>
        <br>
        <select id="color" name="Color">
            <option value="" selected="selected">What Color?</option>
             <option value="black">Black</option>
             <option value="blue">Blue</option>
             <option value="red">Red</option>
             <option value="white">White</option>
             <option value="green">Green</option>
             </select>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="configurator.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$("#car").change(function () {
    transmission();
});

$("#trans").change(function () {
    transmission();
});

function transmission() {
    if ($("#car").val() == "car1" && $("#trans").val() == "auto") {
        $("option[value$='red']").hide();
        $("option[value$='white']").hide();
        $("option[value$='green']").hide();
    } else {
        $("option[value$='red']").show();
        $("option[value$='white']").show();
        $("option[value$='green']").show();
    }
}
```

You will have to make a few tweaks to get your other car & trans combinations working how you want them to (i.e. displaying only the colors you want) by adding more if else statements in the transmission() method but this should get you on your way. This is using jQuery by the way.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwN1n.jpg)

Comment: Thanks. This works. Would it be possible to add an image for each car as well? Where would I put the source?